sdFormat does not automatically calculate moment of inertia
This is the content of the link tag
<link name="join11">
        <pose degrees="true">0 10 0 0 0 0</pose>
        <inertial auto="true">
            <density>1000</density>
        </inertial>
        <collision name="join11colli">
            <density>1000</density>
            <geometry>
                <mesh>
                    <uri>file://home/cbb/gz_models/robot/join.STL</uri>
                </mesh>
            </geometry>
        </collision>
        <visual name="join11visu">
            <geometry>
                <mesh>
                    <uri>file://home/cbb/gz_models/robot/join.STL</uri>
                </mesh>
            </geometry>
            <material>
                <ambient>1 0 0 1</ambient>
                <diffuse>1 0 0 1</diffuse>
                <specular>1 0 0 1</specular>
            </material>
        </visual>
    </link>

this is the warning message
Custom moment of inertia calculator for meshes not set via sdf::ParserConfig::RegisterCustomInertiaCalc, using default inertial values.
But i don't know how to set the ParserConfig

The documentation states the following:

Currently, the mesh inertia calculator does not work well with meshes having submeshes.

Could this be the cause?
If not, I suggest to try the examples shown in the documentation, and then try some simple meshes (preferably generated with different software than your current mesh), to isolate if the problem is caused by your specific mesh or not.

But when I add the mass and Inertia values in the SDF file, the quality property in Gazebo is still the default

I don't know what you mean with "the quality property". In any case, do as I said: try something that you know should work (default shapes, tutorial examples) first, and if these work correctly, build up from there. E.g. check a box shape, and then check identical geometry but with a box mesh. If that all works, then you can conclude that the issue is your mesh. Try to simplify it. If that works, gradually add some complexity. Etc.

It's not clear from your question, but I assume you're trying to run the file through gz sdf to get the computed inertia. The auto inertia feature in SDFormat supports simple shapes, but unfortunately, SDFormat by itself is unable to compute moments of Inertia for meshes since SDFormat doesn't know how to load meshes. That functionality is built into gz sim, so if you run your model with gz sim, it should work. If you need the actual inertia values, you can save the world from gz sim and inspect the resulting .sdf file.
